# Eclipse doesn't find binaries in SW4STM32

Tags: eclipse, stm32, binaries

I'm using workbench SW4STM32 in Eclipse Kepler for C/C++.
Software doesn't find binaries files when I try to debug it. It creates it while building a project, I'm sure of this 'cause I can see them and use in others programms. However it cannot locate them by itself. I rebuilded project many times, I've tried reinstalling workbench, MinGC and changing directory in project properties but neither helped. Have You ever encountered something like this?
Do You have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Show your debug configuration project configuration causey what you posted here is not enough to helo

Comment: You don't have debugger for STM32 installed you could use gdb but if I'm correct it should have openocd for St.

Comment: Btw why not using workbench standalone? It would save you a lot if grief, it's properly set up. I would suggest start from workbench and focus on embedded development then set up your own environment.

Answer (score 0):

I' ve solved it. It turned out I had some binary parsers missing.

Comment: Please share what you were missing